# Why does Annie say "Susan" after Abed proposes calling the group the "Stephen King's Dreamcatchers"?

Tags: community

In the last episode of season 6 of ***Community***, when proposing new names for the Save Greendale Committee, Abed proposes "Stephen King's Dreamcatchers". Annie then looks at him and says "Susan".

Is this a reference to something? Or is Susan a proposed name for the group?

Comment: *"is Susan a proposed name for the group"* Seems like the safest bet.

Comment: It could a "The Tick" reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYmWRNZ_0ys

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of discussion about this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/community/comments/3a6au9/joke_from_the_finale_i_didnt_get/) mostly fed by the theories that this is in some way an inside joke or reference to some deeper Stephen King universe item. This can mainly be attributed to the fact that the name Susan is very common in Stephen King stories, including being the name of Roland Deschain's true love, Susan Delgado, from ***The Dark Tower*** series.

Those familiar with SK's works will probably know that *The Dark Tower* serves as a sort of focal point that connects all of the Stephen King universe through alternate dimensions, or levels of the tower.  Susan is one of the recurring themes through out SK novels that indicate a *Dark Tower* connection, others being references to the number 19, ka or destiny and comparing it to a wheel, a group that is brought together by destiny known as a ka-tet, etc.

All that said, it is possible that Annie's reference to the name Susan was an attempt at a Stephen King in joke, but it seems a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: The problem with their theory is that Susan is funny because it's *nonsensical* and comes out of nowhere. The second it doesn't come out of nowhere and is the result of some tenuous connection, it's not as funny.